# AS3 XOR vs PHP XOR

Tags: php, flash, xor

Here is an odd (I think odd) thing.

```
  PHP: 539013259 ^ 12345 = 538976288
  AS3: 549013259 ^ 12345 = 539001010
```

Any ideas why the values are different? The best I can tell from Xor from both languages, the result should be the same.

Comment: Your input numbers are different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am unable to duplicate this behavior.  At the PHP interactive shell:

```
php > echo 539013259 ^ 12345;
539001010
```

Comment: Thanks...you pointed out to me an error in the code. It was actually supposed to be 539013259 ^ (12345 * 3), which the AS3 code was not doing.